# Add Pod dependency with source to .podspec

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to add the following dependency to my Podspec

```
s.dependency 'Apollo/WebSocket', :git => 'https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios'
```

---

Here's what I get in my Terminal whenever I try to run `pod lib lint MyPodName.podspec`:

```
- ERROR | spec: The specification defined in `MyPodName.podspec` could not be loaded.


[!] Invalid `MyPodName.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements.

 #  from <PathToMyPodspec>/MyPodName.podspec:36
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    
 >    s.dependency 'Apollo/WebSocket', :git => 'https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios'
 #    
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

---

I have successfully used it as a Pod in one of my iOS projects. But now that I am creating a pod myself, I am struggling to understand what I should do to make it work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Still don't understand your problem. Are you getting any error or completely clueless on how to achieve something? Please explain.

Comment: @Anand I'm sorry, my bad. I've extended my question, please, have a look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved!

It turns out that the **Podfile** document of the project plays a major role in all of this. I found it inside the `/Example` folder of said project. What I've done is:

```
use_frameworks!
source = 'https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios'
source = 'https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios'

target 'MyPodName_Example' do

  pod 'Apollo'
  pod 'Apollo/WebSocket'
  pod 'MyPodName', :path => '../'

  target 'MyPodName_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

(I am not quite sure if I necessarily need both of the `source` lines but it does work like this)

Then I ran `pod install` on the `/Example` directory.

After that I returned back to my `MyPodName.podspec` file and edited dependencies to look like this:

```
  s.dependency 'Apollo'
  s.dependency 'Apollo/WebSocket'
```

Then I ran `pod lib lint MyPodName.podspec` on the root directory (where my `.podspec` file is) and this time it succeeded.

---

*NOTICE:*

- I needed both `Apollo` and `Apollo/WebSocket` dependencies.
- I haven't yet pushed my Pod and cannot guarantee that all of this is 100% correct
- I'm new to CocoaPods, so this might not be the most optimal solution to the problem.

Answer (score 15):

It looks like it is not allowed to define dependency in PodSpec like this. Please refer CocoaPod guideline document on [Dependency](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)

It seems it should contain only version information like mentioned below. Other formats are not allowed.

[image]

Comment: Yep, only a Podfile can specify locations for other podspecs.

Comment: Is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 7):

According to this [CocoaPods/issues/2485](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2485), [CocoaPods/issues/922](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/922#issuecomment-15771597), 
the podspecs cannot specify the source of dependencies now.

Alternative:

**For public repo**:

Just use `s.dependency 'Apollo/WebSocket', '~> 0.0.1'` directly.

**If you're specifying a private repo**

Free feel to follow this [blog's](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03) step to create(`pod repo push`)  a private library. Then you should be able to specify your private project by using `s.dependency 'YourPrivateProjectName', '~> 0.0.1'`

Comment: Hello boog: I tried same. But I get "No such module 'MyPrivatePOD'". Can you please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147488/cant-import-my-private-cocoapod-into-another-private-cocoapod

Answer (score 5):

While performing the validation, you need enter the command with the link to the repos where your podspecs are hosted. Something like this
pod lib lint --sources=git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git,git@github.com:otherRepos