# How to add PDFTron as dependency in podspec file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, podfile, pdftron

We have podspec file in the project and I wanted to include PDFTron as dependency spec.

Below is the way i'm adding third party libraries as dependencies in podspec file.

```
-------podspec file--------------------------------------
s.dependency 'SSZipArchive'
s.dependency "SVGKit", "~> 2.1.1"
s.dependency "GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition" 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

PDFTron iOS document provided below formate to download SDK using cocoapods.

pod 'PDFNet', podspec: 'https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/ios/cocoapods/xcframeworks/pdfnet/latest.podspec'

When we add above line in podfile no issue, but when we add in the podspec facing below issue.

[image]

Can any one help me how can we add .podspec path as dependency in another .podspec file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In dependency, you can't specify a URL. So you can't tell to use specific podspec. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency

Comment: See unavailability https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4921 But you might be able to do so for your podfile, if you can register `PDFNet` . See some answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745916/add-pod-dependency-with-source-to-podspec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Pod dependency with source to .podspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745916/add-pod-dependency-with-source-to-podspec)