# source issue with podfile

Tags: cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I'd like to specify version 5.1.0 of the InstaCart TrueTime library in a Podfile instead of 5.0.3. I think this is the only way to use 5.1.0 since 5.0.3 hasn't been added to the master per https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift/issues/97

(The library is pretty outdated unfortunately.)

According to [Add Pod dependency with source to .podspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745916/add-pod-dependency-with-source-to-podspec), the way to do this is add

```
source 'https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift.git'
```

at the top, but I then get the following error with 'pod update':

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `TrueTime`
```

I think this error occurs because the source has TrueTime.podspec at the top level instead of inside a '5.1.0' folder, even though my podspec doesn't specify a version:

```
s.dependency "TrueTime"
```

Is my thinking correct, and is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` attribute is used to refer to a podspec repository, not a single pod.

To accomplish that goal, you could set up a private specs repository and publish the desired podspec there - then refer to the podspec repo from the Podfile.

Details at https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html